# Как грамотно очищать коллекции или объекты Java. Как не сожрать всю память

Tags: java, строки, память

Я решил провести такой эксперимент.

```
public class Main {

    public static final int mew = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    public static final String message = "A0yj8,fghfgh02fdgdrthrtfjfghfghfj";
    public  ArrayList<StringBuilder> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Main main = new Main();
        final StringBuilder sb   = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(message);

        while (true){
            main.clear();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            main.addposition(sb.toString());
        }

    }

    public void clear(){

        for (StringBuilder sb : this.list){
            sb.setLength(0);
        }

        list.clear();
        list = new ArrayList<>(10);

    }

    public  void addposition(String s ){
        for (int i = 0 ; i < mew; i ++){
                this.list.add(new StringBuilder().append(s+1));
        }
    }

}
```

Спустя пару секунд, монитор ресурсов становится красным а затраченная память улетает далеко за 1 гигабайт. Может я что-то делаю неправильно ?

Везде кричат что надо использовать StringBuilder, т.к String не изменяемый.

Comment: ну так вы посчитайте сами, сколько ваша программа должна занимать памяти?

Comment: @tym32167 Здесь она не должна затрачиваться вообще, по идее. В цикле идёт наполнение и очистка в начале витка.

Comment: не знаю про что вы говорите, но я вижу в методе `addposition` большой цикл с добавлением строки в StringBuilder и добавления StringBuilder в list. В конце этого цикла, но перед очисткой, сколько у вас будет съедено памяти?

Comment: для справки, ваш метод `clear()` не очишает память. Он только теряет ссылки на какие то данные, но данные все ешё в памяти. Память будет очищена тогда, когда GC захочет.

Comment: @tym32167 можно как то ограничить потребляемый объём на старте ? ведь пока есть куда расти, GC будет спать ?

Comment: ну вы не потребляйте много памяти, иначе получите out of memory ошибку. Других ограничений нет.

Comment: @tym32167 так как мне её не потреблять, если вы говорите что её нельзя занулить ? ... я уже вообще ничего не понимаю

Comment: @tym32167 извините, получается я банально просто не посчитал, сколько сожрёт за 1 цикл. Это очень глупая ошибка...

Comment: Без проблем! Все приходит с опытом. Рад, что теперь вы разобрались.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `addposition` в цикле 2 миллиарда раз добавляет в список объекты, каждый из которых содержит минимум 34 символа (+ накладные расходы на каждый объект `StringBuilder` и элемент в списке `this.list`). Т.е. при первом же вызове `addposition` самих только данных там минимум 34 * 2 * MAX_INT = 136 гигабайт и под все это идет выделение памяти.

Тут не важно, что делает `clear` вообще.

А вообще чтобы освободить память достаточно убедиться, что на объект нет ни одной обычной ссылки. В этом случае его соберет сборщик мусора. Не обязательно это произойдет сразу (т.к. JVM старается уменьшить накладные расходы на сборку мусора), но если программа запрашивает выделение памяти, а она занята мусором, то перед тем как случится `OutOfMemoryError` будет обязательно сделана полная сборка мусора.

Т.е. в этом случае (если абстрагироваться от того, что идет добавление 2 миллиардов объектов и предположить, что их меньше, так что все вместе они помещаются в доступную JVM память), `list.clear` достаточно, т.к. единственные ссылки на созданные объекты `StringBuilder` хранятся в списке `this.list`. Операция `clear` очистит список и все ссылки на эти объекты будут потеряны.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за развернутый ответ!

Comment: Объясните тупому, как выглядит ссылка на объект? И чем отличается обычная ссылка от необычной?

Comment: Задайте отдельный вопрос - отвечу подробно. А если вкратце, то можно например тут почитать https://javadevblog.com/tipy-ssy-lok-v-java-strongreference-weakreference-softreference-i-phantomreference.html. Когда я писал обычная в ответе, то имел ввиду сильная (`strong`), они используются по умолчанию.